# MS Access - Substitute For Except Using Same Table

Tags: sql, ms-access

Looking for results of all rows for those eventIds where there exists a row for that eventId with a particular position and sub position, but there does NOT EXIST any row with that position and a null subposition. I did it in MS SQL using the EXCEPT keyword; however, MS Access fails on EXCEPT. Is there a way to do this query in MS Access:

```
 SELECT Distinct  eventID FROM table   WHERE Position = '123' AND SubPosition = 'ABC'
 AND pool = 'something'
 AND Status = 'active'
 AND area = '1'
 EXCEPT
 SELECT Distinct  eventID FROM table   WHERE Position = '123' AND SubPosition  IS NULL
 AND pool = 'something'
 AND Status = 'active'
 AND area = '1'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along the lines of an outer join to find where there's no null match and then filter on there being no null match.

```
SELECT  *
FROM (select * from Table1 where subposition is not null) as hasSubPosition
left join (select * from Table1 where subposition is null) AS noSubPosition
on 
hasSubPosition.eventid = noSubPosition.eventid and
hasSubPosition.position = noSubPosition.position and
hasSubPosition.pool = noSubPosition.pool and
hasSubPosition.status = noSubPosition.status and
hasSubPosition.area = noSubPosition.area
where noSubPosition.eventid is null
```

Comment: Tweaked it and it worked. Thanks a bunch for your help!